# Finding anagrams of a specific word in a list

Tags: python, anagram

So, the problem is:

Given an array of m words and 1 other word, find all anagrams of that word in the array and print them.

Do y’all have any faster algorithm?:)

I’ve succesfully coded this one, but it seems rather slow ( i’ve been using sorted() with a for loop + checking the length before). Found anagrams were added to a new array. Then printing the list of anagrams with a for loop again.

Comment: `I’ve succesfully coded this one` - let's see it then!

Answer (score 0):

I think that counting characters and comparing it will be faster but im not sure. Just check it ;)

`defaultdict` will be helpful.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

def char_counter(word: str)-> dict
    result = dd(int)
    for c in word:
        result[c]+=1
    return result
```

Comment: If you're using a class from `collections` (which is ofc fine) then use `Counter`: `Counter(word)` does the same as your function.